# How to specify which process architecture needs to deploy pyqt5 application using nuitka?

Tags: python, pyqt

Try deploying pyqt5 application on the raspberry pi but my bin file is not compatible with arm64 processor architecture. How can I fix this?

Development pyqt5 application work on windows 10 using qt creator. But I need to create a self-contained file that can run on raspberry pi3. When I made the file the same file I could not run it on raspberry pi 3. Maybe I have a problem with the architecture of the process presbyter pi use arm I develop on x64.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.